# Tooltips on check boxes

Tags: development, javascript

I have a CheckBoxList , I want to assign tooltip to all the checkboxes. How is it possible? I cannot find any property associated with this.

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="XYZ" RepeatColumns="3" Width="300" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST01" Value="ST01" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST02" Value="ST02" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST03" Value="ST03" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST04" Value="ST04" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST05" Value="ST05" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST06" Value="ST06" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST07" Value="ST07" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST08" Value="ST08" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="ST09" Value="ST09" />
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it

```
    foreach (ListItem li in cblAffectedST.Items) 
    { 
        li.Attributes.Add("title", "ToolTip of Text " + (i + 1).ToString());
        i++; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have also added the Title to your markup like: `<asp:ListItem Text="ST01" Value="ST01" Title="This is a tooltip!"/>`

I know it might not show in Autocomplete, but it does work.